# jQuery selector check for specific text(domain extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

How can I check if email input contains specific domain extensions like .com, .at, net...?
Is there a jQuery selector that can help me?

```
Email Address: <input type='text' id='txtEmail'/><br/>
<input type='submit' id='btnValidate' Value='Validate Email' />
```

```css
body
{
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    Font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#btnValidate').click(function() {
        var sEmail = $('#txtEmail').val();
        if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
            alert('Please enter valid email address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
            alert('Email is valid');
        }
        else {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kUxcz/422/

Comment: A typo, You have to pass event argument in `$('#btnValidate').click(function() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/kUxcz/423/)

```
newemail = sEmail.split('').reverse().join('')
newemail = newemail.split('.')[0].split('').reverse().join('');
```

Comment: Why get the second element in the array? What if the email address is `foo.bar.org.location@sub.main.co.uk`?

Comment: what if id is amit.jain@hotmail.com??

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated my answer please check it once.

Answer (score 1):

Try this by using negative value to split from last:

```
sEmail.split('.')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

split it using

```
arr =  sEmail.split('.');

domain = arr[arr.length-1];
```

or

```
var domain = sEmail.substring(sEmail.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, sEmail.length);
```